# I can't see why this code doesn't turn a heading into a correct link

Tags: php, regex

I have a following string in my database:

```
"Minecraft is a sandbox video game developed by Mojang Studios from Sweden. Its concept revolve around procedurally generated world made of cubic blocks.

Minecraft is the best-selling game in history, having over 238 millions of copies sold.

<h1>Gameplay</h1>

Minecraft is played from first-person perspective. Gameplay includes mining, crafting, combat, building and terraforming. Usually when a new single-player game is started, a player is placed into a procedurally generated world. The player can encounter various "mobs"...
```

I'm trying to extract heading value from the string and turn it into a link using following code

```
    $heading='';
    $match1=array();
    $matched=preg_match("/<h\d>/",$part,$match1,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    if($matched)
    {
        $match2=array();

        preg_match("#</h\d>#",$part,$match2,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        $heading= substr($part,$match1[0][1]+4,$match2[0][1]);
        $heading="<a href='$heading'>$heading</a>";
    }
```

I expect the 'heading' variable to be `<a href='Gameplay'></a>`, but the result is `<a href='Gameplay Minecraft is played from first-person perspective. Gameplay includes mining, crafting, combat, building and terraforming. Usually when a new single-player game is started, a player is placed into a procedurally generated world. The player can encou' > Gameplay Minecraft is played from first-person perspective. Gameplay includes mining, crafting, combat, building and terraforming. Usually when a new single-player game is started, a player is placed into a procedurally generated world. The player can encou</a>`

So, it extends up to 'encou', and I can't see why

Comment: You are passing `$match1[0][1]+4` as the offset  (which is 248) and `$match2[0][1]` as the length (which is 256) to [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) Why not get the gameplay with `<h(\d)>(.*?)</h\1>` and get the capture group 2 value or use a domparser?

Answer (score 1):

Building on the comment by @theforthbird - you can capture the string you want with a single regex, although in general parsing HTML with regex leads to a world of pain so while this may work for your current purposes, if you need to be doing more stuff along these lines, you'd be better off parsing the HTML as a DOM and extracting what you need.

```
$heading = '';
preg_match('/<h(\d)>(.*?)<\/h\1>/', $string, $matches);

// print_r($matches); # uncomment this to see everything that was 'matched' by this regex

if (!empty($matches[2])) {
    $heading = "<a href='{$matches[2]}'></a>";
}
```